# Identify this Dragonlance(?) story with clever use of footnotes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dragonlance

Please help me identify a short story I remember reading ten or twenty years ago.  It was probably in one of the *Dragonlance* books (maybe in the *Tales* series).  I don't remember much of the plot.  What I do remember clearly was its unusual and creative stylistic device:  the story was presented as a document written by a verbose and detail-minded chronicler—probably a Gnome—who was particularly fond of footnotes.  The footnotes were notable for their great number and enormous length, and were probably also nested (that is, even the footnotes had footnotes).  I imagine the typesetter must have had lots of fun with this story!  I would love to get my hands on it again.

Comment: Footnotes inside footnotes isn't completely unusual: Terry Pratchett does it all the time, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that this my be "*Into the Heart of the Story*" by Michael Williams.  It was in the first Dragonlance Tales Trilogy book [Kender, Gully Dwarves and Gnomes](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Kender,_Gully_Dwarves,_and_Gnomes_%28anthology%29).  It was told from the point of a gnome named Virum and discusses the background of some of the songs of the heroes of the War of the Lance.

Comment: I purchased a copy of the book and confirmed that this is the story I was thinking of.  It seems my memory was somewhat faulty, though; while the footnotes are notable for their number, length, and source of humour, they aren't actually nested.

Comment: Michael Williams songs were an automatic skip for me in every book.